# C#からFirebase Cloud MessagingのPush通知送信できません

Tags: c#, firebase

#### 前提・実現したいこと

FirebaseのCloudMessagingでC#からAndroid、iOS端末に向けてPush通知の送信をしたいと思っています。
両OSともにコンソール画面からのPush通知の確認はできています。

C#で下記の実装を行い、Push通知を送信しようとしたところエラーが表示されています。
どなたか知恵をお貸しいただけないしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

エラー内容

```
{"multicast_id":3610244537268820506,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

ソースコード

```
private void SendBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    tRequest.Method = "post";
    //serverKey - Key from Firebase cloud messaging server  
    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", "{サーバーキー}"));
    //Sender Id - From firebase project setting  
    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", "{送信者 ID}"));
    tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    var payload = new
    {
        to = "{端末のトークンID}",
        priority = "high",
        content_available = true,
        notification = new
        {
            body = "Test",
            title = "Test",
            badge = 1
        },
    };

    string postbody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload).ToString();
    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postbody);
    tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (dataStreamResponse != null) using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                {
                    String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(sResponseFromServer);
                    //result.Response = sResponseFromServer;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: エラーはおそらくこれでしょうか。[ダウンストリーム メッセージのエラー レスポンス コード](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref?hl=ja#error-codes)  それからC#ではなく他の言語やシステムですが、この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[Firebase プッシュ通知 InvalidRegistration (コンソールからはそのトークンに送信できる)](https://teratail.com/questions/103476), [InvalidRegistration error in Firebase Cloud Messaging for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39614607/9014308), [Firebase FCM error: 'InvalidRegistration'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44035518/9014308), ["error": "InvalidRegistration" while sending push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55594820/9014308)

Comment: @kunif エラーコード表と参考URLをご教示いただきありがとうございます。しかし、解決には至りませんでした。他にもなにかご存じだったりしませんか？

Comment: 私も検索結果を紹介しているだけなので詳しいことは分かりません。エラーメッセージや紹介記事からすると、何か必要なトークンの設定が不足しているか形式を間違えているか、といった感じですが。あとはガラッとやり方が変わりますが、こちらの仕組みに従って新しい方法でアクセスしてみるとか。[以前の HTTP から HTTP v1 に移行する](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1?hl=ja)